# KAL Calendar does not allow select any row for the list of events tableview

Tags: ios, iphone

I used below code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {

      EKEventStore * store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(dateSelected:) name:@"D" object:nil];

        KalViewController *kal = [[KalViewController alloc] init];
        kal.delegate = self;
        kal.title= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",kal.selectedDate];
        [kal loadView];

        EventKitDataSource * dataSource = [[EventKitDataSource alloc]init];
        kal.dataSource = dataSource;

         navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:kal];
        [self.customView addSubview:kal.view];
```

// when I add  kal.view inside of my custom view then It displays the list of events and when I click on any row then It does not get pushed to next view screen

```
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to make change two changes in KalView.m file..

**First**:In that class,there is an initwithFrame method in which you will get this below code.In that you can change color as per your requirement..

```
   UIView *headerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, frame.size.width, kHeaderHeight)] autorelease];
headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
[self addSubviewsToHeaderView:headerView];
[self addSubview:headerView];
```

**Second** :In the same class ,there is a one more method i.e addSubviewsToHeaderView:
In that method you will get this code

```
//Header background gradient
UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Kal.bundle/kal_grid_background.png"]];
CGRect imageFrame = headerView.frame; 
imageFrame.origin = CGPointZero;
backgroundView.frame = imageFrame;
[headerView addSubview:backgroundView];
[backgroundView release];
```

Comment this whole code because this is setting image in HeaderView..

Comment: thanks for ur reply ankit but when I place above code in addSubviewsToHeaderView method  at that time It displays image in entire calendar view.

Comment: It also hides that dates and tiles of calendar view.

Comment: In ViewDidload,try to addsubview only KalViewController to your ViewController

Comment: kal = [[KalViewController alloc] init];
    kal.delegate = self;
    kal.title= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",kal.selectedDate];
    [kal loadView];

    dataSource = [[EventKitDataSource alloc]init];
    kal.dataSource = dataSource;
    
    navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:kal];
//    [calView addSubview:navController.view];
    // when I comment this above line then User is not be able to navigate from Calendar to event details screen
    
    [calView addSubview:kal.view];

Comment: Your ViewController should be embedded with Navigation Controller and On  didSelectRowAtIndexPath: of TableView Method ,navigate viewController to another viewController

Comment: If I embed it in a view did load then  didSelectRowAtIndexPath do not get called 
    
    when i write in viedidload following lines then  
    
 
    navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:kal];                                                 
        [self.cutomView addSubview:kal.view];                                                                                                                                                                                                In this case didselect does not get worked

Comment: you should Add your viewController in UINavigationController and addSubView the KalViewController in viewcontroller..

Comment: yes arpit i have added calendar view in my custom uiview

Comment: navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:kal];
    [cusomview addSubview:navController.view];

Comment: in this case i can be able to move to next by did select but it is not showing me next previous buttons and header of calandar view

Comment: For example:
IF ViewController is as Initial ViewController

In Appdelegate, didFinishLaunching method
[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewcontroller];

And addSubView KalViewCalender in ViewController in ViewDidLoad
[viewController.view addSubView:Kal.view]

Comment: Brother I have used storyboard so how to write that code in AppDelegate

Comment: Then SIMPLY EMBED THE UINAVIGATION CONTROLLER TO THE VIEWCONTROLLER

Comment: ye i did in story board and i wrote following code               [myCUSTOMVIEW addSubview:kal.view];

Comment: Ok In Storyboard,uncheck the Under Top Bar in viewController property

Comment: ya bro i have unchecked in storyboard it but also it is not working properly Please help me

Comment: Now Is it showing Header View and tableViewdidselect method is not working?

Comment: navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:kal];

    [calView addSubview:kal.view];

Comment: If i write above lines then It shows me next previous buttons and header bar but it does not allow me to navigate from this controller to another

Comment: If I write [calView addSubview:navController.view]; then It allows me navigation but it does not display next/previous buttons and header bar of calendar view

Comment: Did you Implement KalView Delegate method 
- (void)didSelectDate:(KalDate *)date;
In this method ,you can push to next viewController . This is for First Scenario

Comment: sorry bro but if i write push code  in  didSelectDate method then I will select any date from kalendar view then also it will be pushed